# When did constant 0 in pointer context acquire its special status?

Tags: c, history

As you know, in standard modern C language the constant 0 value used in pointer context acts as a *null-pointer constant*, which gets converted to a platform-specific (and possibly even type-specific) *null-pointer value*.

Meanwhile, the early versions of C language, as the one described in [C Reference Manual](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/cman.pdf), did not make much of a distinction between pointer and integer contexts, allowing one to freely compare and assign integers to pointers. If am not mistaken, in that version of C the constant 0 had no special status, meaning that assigning the value of constant 0 to a pointer would simply make it point to physical address 0 (just like assigning the value of 42 to a pointer would make it point to physical address 42).

In ANSI C things have changed significantly. Now assigning the constant 0 to a pointer will place some platform-specific *null-pointer value* into that pointer. Null-pointer value is not required to be represented by physical 0 value.

So, at what point in the history of C language did it change from one to another? Did K&R C already incorporate the higher-level concept of null-pointer with constant 0 given its special status? Or did the K&R C still guarantee physical assignment of integers to pointers even for constant 0?

Comment: "Now assigning the constant 0 to a pointer will place some platform-specific null-pointer value into that pointer."  This is new to me; is it really true?  What's the most commonly-used platform/compiler where this is true, i.e. where `void * x = 0;` writes a physical value other than 0 into `x`.

Comment: @David Grayson: Well, firstly, this is really true, yes. At the abstract language level, of course. Secondly, most (all) popular platforms today use address 0x0 as null pointer value, so you will indeed see 0 in your pointer. Conceptually, however, it is not the same integral 0 you assigned to it :) Thirdly, C FAQ (http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) has some examples of [exotic] platforms with non-zero null pointers. Fourthly, there's nothing that prevents one from taking GCC sources and modifying them to use a non-zero physical value for null-pointers (if one has nothing better to do).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the FAQ of my question!  It looks like all the machines mentioned are really old.  I'm not going to lose sleep over using a 0 in a spot where NULL would suffice, but I can understand why purists would shudder.

Comment: @David Grayson: Er... Apparently you misunderstood something. No purist will ever shudder over `0` being used instead of `NULL`. In pointer context these two are *totally equivalent and interchangeable* (read the other FAQ entries). The language guarantees it. Purists will shudder if you start using `memset` (or `calloc`) on data that contains pointers inside, expecting it to initialize your pointers to nulls. That is NOT guaranteed by the language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It goes back to *nearly* the beginning of C (if not the very beginning). If you look on page 21 of the [January 1974 C reference manual](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/cman74.pdf), it's more or less directly stated in some sample code:

```
/* is pointer null? */
if (p == 0) {
```

Going back still a bit further, to [ca. 1972-73 PDP-11/20 compiler](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/last1120c/c10.c), we find:

```
match(tree, table, nreg)
int tree[], table[]; {
    extern opdope[], dcalc, notcompat;
    int op, d1, d2, t1, t2, p1[], p2[];
    char mp[];

    if (tree==0)
        return(0);
    op = *tree;
```

At least if I'm reading this correctly, the `if (tree==0)` line is checking that `tree` is a non-null pointer before attempting to dereference it.

Unfortunately, [Dennis says](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/primevalC.html) he can't be much more certain about the date than "1972-73".

There isn't much history of C before that. Nonetheless, there does seem to be a bit of history of 0 being treated as a null pointer. It looks to me like use of 0 as a null pointer is something that C "inherited" from Unix. The entry for `exec` in the [November 1971 1<sup>st</sup> Edition Unix programmer's manual](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/man21.pdf) shows a pointer with the value 0 to signal the end of the list of arguments. According to [Dennis' description](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/1stEdman.html), at this point "C was still to come."

Based on all this, I'd tentatively conclude that C treated 0 as a null pointer from the very beginning, or at least so early on that there's probably no longer any record of a version of the language that was otherwise.

I haven't been nearly as successful at tracking down documentation about the first point at which a null pointer might have had non-zero bits. From the viewpoint of the *language*, this has *never* been relevant. I suspect it happened fairly early on, but finding documentation to support that would be difficult. One of the earliest ports of C was to [IBM System/360 mainframes](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/c_evolution.html), and although I can't find direct documentation of it, my *guess* would be that internally the null pointer value used on these machines was probably non-zero. I don't have the exact number handy, but I know that PL/I on these machines used a non-zero value for its equivalent of a null pointer; I'd *guess* that when they ported C to these machines, they *probably* used the same value.

Comment: I saw the comments in CRM, but it is pretty obvious to me that null pointer in that case stands for physical zero-address pointer. The "normative" portion of document itself (if one can call it that) does not mention null pointer at all. Basically, in CRM "null pointer" was just a gentleman's agreement with no support from the language. With the very same degree of success they could have decided to use one-pointer (address 0x1) as "special" value for pointers.

Comment: My question is about a totally different thing. My question is about the point in time when C started to allow non-zero representations for null pointers. I.e. one does `p = 0`, but one gets `p` that points to a non-zero physical address. ANSI C allows this to be the case. When did this become allowed?

Comment: @AndreyT: That's what I address in my last paragraph. My guess is that it was never disallowed, but *probably* first used when C was ported to System/360 mainframes (though I haven't found any direct documentation of that).

Answer (score 3):

[See the C-faq question 5.4](http://c-faq.com/null/macro.html)

As a matter of style, many programmers prefer not to have unadorned 0's scattered through their programs, some representing numbers and some representing pointers. Therefore, the preprocessor macro NULL is defined (by several headers, including  and ) as a null pointer constant, typically 0 or ((void *)0) (see also question 5.6). A programmer who wishes to make explicit the distinction between 0 the integer and 0 the null pointer constant can then use NULL whenever a null pointer is required.

Using NULL is a stylistic convention only; the preprocessor turns NULL back into 0 which is then recognized by the compiler, in pointer contexts, as before. In particular, a cast may still be necessary before NULL (as before 0) in a function call argument. The table under question 5.2 above applies for NULL as well as 0 (an unadorned NULL is equivalent to an unadorned 0).

NULL should be used only as a pointer constant; see question 5.9.

```
References: K&R1 Sec. 5.4 pp. 97-8
K&R2 Sec. 5.4 p. 102
ISO Sec. 7.1.6, Sec. 6.2.2.3
Rationale Sec. 4.1.5
H&S Sec. 5.3.2 p. 122, Sec. 11.1 p. 292
```

[**What is this infamous null pointer anyways?**](http://c-faq.com/null/null1.html)

The language definition states that for each pointer type, there is a special value--the "null pointer"--which is distinguishable from all other pointer values and which is "guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function." That is, a null pointer points definitively nowhere; it is not the address of any object or function. The address-of operator & will never yield a null pointer, nor will a successful call to malloc.[footnote] (malloc does return a null pointer when it fails, and this is a typical use of null pointers: as a "special" pointer value with some other meaning, usually "not allocated" or "not pointing anywhere yet.")

A null pointer is conceptually different from an uninitialized pointer. A null pointer is known not to point to any object or function; an uninitialized pointer might point anywhere. See also questions 1.30, 7.1, and 7.31.

As mentioned above, there is a null pointer for each pointer type, and the internal values of null pointers for different types may be different. Although programmers need not know the internal values, the compiler must always be informed which type of null pointer is required, so that it can make the distinction if necessary (see questions 5.2, 5.5, and 5.6).

```
References: K&R1 Sec. 5.4 pp. 97-8
K&R2 Sec. 5.4 p. 102
ISO Sec. 6.2.2.3
Rationale Sec. 3.2.2.3
H&S Sec. 5.3.2 pp. 121-3
```

Finally, only *constant* integral expressions with value 0 are guaranteed to indicate null pointers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure AndreyT knows _what_ `NULL` is.

Comment: @James: I don't know what he knows.. This is not just for him but future passerbys too!

Comment: @Code Monkey: Well, that's not what my question is about. It is not really about what null pointer is. As James noted, I know perfectly well what it is. The question is: at what point of history of C language did the *modern* concept of "null pointer" appear? One can find mentions of "null pointer" in CRM as well, but there it just stands for a pointer to address 0. The modern concept of *null-pointer value* did not exist in CRM yet. When did it appear first? ANSI C? Did K&R C stick with CRM or was it already like ANSI C in that regard?

Comment: A *null pointer constant* is either a constant integral expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to void*.

Comment: @AndreyT: See the references provided. I don't have them readily available but the answers are in there.

Comment: @Code Monkey: I read K&R, but the wording there does not make it explicitly clear whether the intent was to stick with CRM behavior or to introduce the new behavior. Hence the question.

Comment: @Code Monkey: The wording the author uses in the 2nd sin is rather questionable. It is not clear what version of C he's talking about. "The poor thing can't tell the difference between a zero integer constant and NULL"... In pointer context there shouldn't be any difference.